# jquery sending cross domain data via A $.post

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp, getjson, .post

I am trying to send data over to a cakephp (mvc) website, via $.post(). below is the code

```
$('#testReq').click(function () {
    console.log('Button Works');
    $.post('http://play.anthonylgordon.com/usersessions/store/', { data: 'test7' }, function (data) {
        //data contains the json object retrieved.
        console.log(data.status);
    }, "json");
})
```

Below is the cakephp data that retrieves the data and stores it. If you know cake, great but if not it's fine. I am really trying to figure out if i am sending the data correctly

```
<?php
    class UsersessionsController extends AppController {
        var $name = 'Usersessions';
        var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form','Ajax');
        var $components = array('RequestHandler');


        function store()
        {
           Configure::write('debug', 0);
           $this->autoRender = false;
           echo 'hello';
            if ($this->params['url']['data'])
            {
                $this->data['Usersession']['data'] = $this->params['url']['data'];
                $this->Usersession->Save($this->data);
                echo 'Success';
            }   
        }
    }
?>
```

As you can see I put 'hello' before it does any evaluating. I should be able to see that in my console but I dont. I tried this method with the get and I did see the response 'hello'. Which is leaving me to the conclusion that you can not send data CROSS domain via `$.post`. The only method that seems to work is `getJSON()` unless someone can prove me wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot perform ordinary cross domain ajax requests. You need to use [JSONP](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON) and this works only with GET requests (that's because jquery injects a `script` tag to the DOM in order to perform the request and a `script` tag can only use GET to fetch javascript).

Comment: thanx, I was asking people this and they kept bringing up the suggestion to use $.post. so I had mix thoughts about rather i could use it or not. thanks for clearing that up.!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to do requests cross-domain, you'll need to implement a HTTP proxy on your domain which would make HTTP requests on your behalf via a server side utility/library like Curl or Apache [HTTPClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) or something.

**Edit:** JSONP is a solution, but I wouldn't recommend it unless you only need to make GET requests (because that's all that works).  JSONP also isn't necessarily REST-friendly, especially in your case where you need to make a POST request.  If POST satisfies the semantics of your resource and how you intend to manipulate it, switching to GET just to use JSONP feels ugly to me.

Comment: I am not familiar with this at all. do you know of any good resources that talk about this in more detail ?

Comment: Here's a good article about the ideas behind an HTTP proxy: http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html